# Why Laravel does not make lots of queries when using exists on relations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have such entities as:

- Company
- Person

Company `hasMany` Persons. So in the `persons` table there is `company_id` column.

I return company list, which I pass to `CompanyResource`. There I return `has_persons => $this->persons()->exists()` value.

Then I checked the result of `DB::getQueryLog()` and I found out that there is only one SQL query, which does not have `count` or anything like that.

In order to count how many persons a company has, Laravel should make one query per company, shouldn't it? Like `select count (*) from persons where company_id = 5` for example

Comment: "I found out that there is only one SQL query" Can you show this query?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->persons->count()
```